# PDT returning 423 as first line before success?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to get PDT working in the sandbox, and have just run afoul of the problem of using HTTP 1.1 as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14701946/391615

Having changed everything, when I create my connection to

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

// read the body data 
$res = '';
while (!feof($fp)) 
{
    $line = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    // etc...
```

I find that the very first lines return look like this:

```
423
SUCCESS
mc_gross=240.00
invoice=PP0000
protection_eligibility=Partially+Eligible+-+INR+Only
address_status=unconfirmed
```

Any idea what the 423 is all about?

Comment: Further Info:  The 423 comes when using a test business account based in Italy.  I just tried with a different test account (based in USA) which returned 3bc

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like the first line is the number of characters in hex that are in the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

Well here we go:
[PHP fsockopen() / fread() returns messed up data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279652/php-fsockopen-fread-returns-messed-up-data)

Looks like it's chunked data being returned from the server

Comment: More detail here:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/instant-payment-notifications-ipn-payment-data-transfer-pdt/pdt-no-longer-returns-success-first-line